# Не могу сделать дз по Python, буду очень благодарен тому кто поможет(дз самого легкого уровня)I cant do homework

Tags: python

Генерируйте случайные числа, в диапазоне от 0 до 100, до тех пор, пока не сгенерируется 10 чисел в диапазоне от 11 до 27
Как только нужное количество будет сгенерировано, цикл закончится (break), а на экран выведется количество затраченных попыток

Generate random numbers, ranging from 0 to 100, until 10 numbers are generated in the range 11 to 27
As soon as the required amount is generated, the loop will end (break), and the number of attempts will be displayed on the screen.

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерируй массив рандомных чисел, циклом в 100 шагов. Потом проверяй его тем же циклом, ифом проверяй если число меньше 27 но больше 11, то записывай его в другой массив. А если размер того другого массива больше или равен 10, то break;